# Pygame rectangle fill with color and border with different colors

Tags: python, pygame

I want to draw a rectangle filled with one color and border with another color. Something like this:

[image]

And I can draw two rectangles, one is filled with some color and the other one has just borders:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, "red", (100, 100, 100, 100))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, "green", (100, 100, 100, 100), 5)
```

But, is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

Technically there is no better way. You have to draw 2 rectangles. A rectangle can only have one uniform color. There is no separate argument for the color of the border. See [`pygame.draw.rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect). You can write it with one line of code ([list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)), but you still have to draw 2 rectangles:

```py
[pygame.draw.rect(screen, c, (100, 100, 100, 100), w) for c, w in [("red", 0), ("green", 5)]]
```

Comment: Please no, this is not what OP asked for, this is unreadable and not clean in any way. OP didn't ask to do a one-liner and even if that was the question, it is easy to do a shorter one-liner like: ``[*map(pygame.draw.rect, [screen]*2, ["red", "green"], (100, 100, 100, 100)*2, (0, 2)]`` 8 characters less! and even if you'd add spaces around "*"s it still would be 4 characters of optimization.

Answer (score -1):

There is no built-in pygame function to achieve what you want, but as you've shown, it is unnecessary - drawing two rectangles on top of each other will work how you want. Calling `pygame.draw.rect` twice in two different lines is clean enough, but it might get messy when you have multiple locations when you draw such rectangles (or any other shape). Then, your best shot is to write a custom function like:

```py
def draw_colored_rect(surface: pygame.Surface, inside_color, rect, border_color=None, border_width: int = 0):
    if border_color is None:
        border_color = inside_color
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, inside_color, rect)
    if border_width:
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, border_color, rect, border_width)

# And use it like:
draw_colored_rect(screen, "green", (100, 100, 100, 100), "red", 5)
```

I'm not aware of any way that could make that more clean.

If you really want to make that function feel like it is provided by pygame, you can use monkey-patching. Although this is not recommended and instead of improving the code readability, this will hurt it, I'll show how to do that, as someone might find this helpful:

```py
# When accessing the documentation with help(some_method), help provides information about from what file/module such method originates.
# But to find that information, it uses a naive way of just reading the content of some_method.__module__
# So here we override it, to fake the origin.
draw_colored_rect.__module__ = "pygame.draw"
# Changing the members of a module is as simple as this, but note that if you want to change a class member, where class is written in C (a somewhat built-in class), it is more complicated.
pygame.draw.colored_rect = draw_colored_rect
```

And access it afterwards with:

```py
pygame.draw.colored_rect(screen, "green", (100, 100, 100, 100), "red", 5)
```

But you need to run that code before accessing the function, also any static type-checker will scream at you when you try to access the `pygame.draw.colored_rect` (To prevent this you can tell such type-checker to ignore that error on that line, usually with a comment with a specific content, but it may differ from type-checker to type-checker or even worse you can also edit the pygame stub files...)

I think, that monkey-patching in this case would only be useful, if you were implementing some extension to pygame, that would improve some functionalities, but it is still messy.

Comment: This is not what the questioner intended. The questioner was looking for a Pygame API function that can draw a rectangle with a border. The questioner knows how to draw a rectangle with a border by calling `pygame.draw.rect` twice.

Comment: @Rabbid76 ``I want to draw a rectangle filled with one color and border with another color. And I can draw two rectangles, one is filled with some color and the other one has just borders: [CODE] But, is there any better way?`` It's a nitpicking, but THERE IS NO MENTION ABOUT LOOKING FOR A PYGAME API FUNCTION. The OP asked whether there is a better way of drawing such rectangle than with two ``pygame.draw.rect`` calls.  My answer literally comes down to: "No, there isn't a better way of doing it, the only way to improve is to create a custom function for that".

Comment: You have completely misunderstood the question

Comment: @Rabbid76 was right. Indeed, I was looking for a Pygame API function that can draw a rectangle with a border

Comment: Seems like I'm being misunderstood here and my comments being deleted. If your question was about whether such API exists, then fine (but it isn't obvious in your question and neither the other answer does any better) - I've edited my answer to make my point clearer - there is no built-in function in pygame library that can do that in one call and the best way of doing it is implementing one yourself.